# Добавление динамического количества элементов с помощью ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Есть приложение на ASP.NET MVC, в котором предусмотрена возможность добавлять заказы на печать публикаций. Публикация может содержать несколько авторов, количество которых заранее неизвестно. Не совсем представляю себе, как можно организовать такое добавление, т.к. возникает проблема на уровне Вью - как это будет организовано на View, и как во ViewModel. Как в Action прокинуть список этих авторов? Какие существуют способы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подобный случай хорошо описан в статье [Model Binding To A List](https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/)